# Calculating Density of Raster cells in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-statistics

Is there a way to calculate the density of a raster cells in ArcGIS?

The dataset I have is of ground points (there are some cells assigned no-value) and I want to calculate the density of points so that I can chose the best interpolation method.

Comment: how do you want to measure density? pixels per square foot?

Comment: Is your raster a Lidar point cloud derivative? If so, do you have access to the original point cloud data?

Comment: Are you trying to get an 'average number of pulses' over the whole raster? Or do you have a target density and want to calculate pass/fail? If you calculate the statistics with 0 as NoData you will be able to see the min/max/mean/standard deviation for the whole raster excluding cells with no pulses. If your cell size is 1 metre then the mean will be the average number of pulses per square metre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Focal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm) to calculate the sum of cells within a rectangular moving window.

From the documentation:

> Calculates for each input cell location a statistic of the values
>   within a specified neighborhood around it.

The following example shows focal statistics calculated within a 3x3 rectangular neighborhood.

[image]

```
OutRas = FocalStatistics(InRas1, NbrRectangle(3,3,MAP), "SUM", "")
```